# FFMPEG Command to format videos to TikTok's specs?

Tags: ffmpeg, tiktok

I'm trying upload a video exported by windows video editor to tiktok. It's a .mp4 file, and while it does upload, it isn't "TikTok'd", meaning, it only takes up the middle of screen. I was wondering what the ffmpeg command would be to output a video to TikToks specs.

Here's how it currently looks.

[image: TikTok bad format]

And here's how I want it to look.

[image]

Comment: i added some screenshots.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [crop](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop) filter to convert horizontal to vertical video:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "crop=ih*(9/16):ih" -crf 21 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

- This will make it 9:16 aspect ratio.
- `-crf` controls quality. See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264). 18-23 should be a good enough for a TikTok video.
- Audio is [stream copied](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (`-c:a copy`). If you get an error because your audio isn't compatible with MP4 then remove `-c:a copy` and AAC will be automatically used instead.